# Weird result of DensityPlot - drastic changes because of slight modifications of plot range

Tags: plotting

```
DensityPlot[
 Max[0, 0.1 - Abs[1. - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]],
 {x, -1.1, 1.1}, {y, -1.1, 1.1},
 ColorFunction -> (Opacity[#, Blue] &), Frame -> False]
```

This prints out nicely (well, almost...):

[image]

But a slight modification of the plot range is enough to change the result drastically:

```
DensityPlot[
 Max[0, 0.1 - Abs[1. - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]],
 {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1.2, 1.2},
 ColorFunction -> (Opacity[#, Blue] &), Frame -> False]
```

[image]

This effect seems to be closely tied to this particular data. A change in parameters or the formula makes the ring filled again.

```
DensityPlot[
 Max[0, 0.1 - Abs[1.3 - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]],
 {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1.2, 1.2},
 ColorFunction -> (Opacity[#, Blue] &), Frame -> False]

DensityPlot[
 Max[0, Abs[1. - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]],
 {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1.2, 1.2}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Opacity[#, Blue] &), Frame -> False]
```

Both of the above print out as expected.

Why does this happen? How to prevent it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that `PlotRange` must be specified to assure that the `Full` range of data is displayed in the second `DensityPlot`.  Also, specifying `PlotPoints` improves the appearance of the first `DensityPlot`.

```
DensityPlot[Max[0, 0.1 - Abs[1. - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]], {x, -1.1, 1.1}, {y, -1.1, 1.1}, 
ColorFunction -> (Opacity[#, Blue] &), PlotPoints -> 100, Frame -> False, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

```
DensityPlot[Max[0, 0.1 - Abs[1. - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]], {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1.2, 1.2}, 
ColorFunction -> (Opacity[#, Blue] &), PlotPoints -> 100, Frame -> False, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

**Update - Corresponding 1-D behavior**

`Plot` exhibits similar behavior

```
Plot[Max[0, 0.1 - Abs[1. - Sqrt[x^2]]], {x, -1.2, 1.2}]
```

[image]

omits part of the curve unless `PlotPoints` is set to `100` or more.  And,

```
Plot[Max[0, 0.1 - Abs[1. - Sqrt[x^2]]], {x, -1.1, 1.1}]
```

[image]

has far too small a `PlotRange`, unless it is set explicitly to `All` or `Full`.  This same behavior persists for ranges as large as about `{x, -1.14, 1.14}`, and as small as about `{x, -1.09, 1.09}`.  It is not uncommon that Mathematica plotting routines have difficulty with functions that are zero except in narrow ranges.

Comment: All right, thanks. But... why...? Why do I have to specify `PlotRange` since I've already specified the range with  `{x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1.2, 1.2}` and obviously the whole ring is within that range?

Comment: @gaazkam The problem is not with `PlotRange` for `x` and `y` but for the function you were plotting. `Plot` has this problem too.  I shall add a bit more to my answer.